# dell xps m1330: hardware malfunction error

Tags: hardware-failure, memory-error

Recently, a old Dell XPS m1330 laptop started throwing the error below.  It appears to be a memory hardware problem.  Is there anything I can do to diagnose the issue?
[image: HW Malfunction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run a memory tester
http://www.memtest.org/

Download the prebuilt ISO, burn it to CD as an Image (not data), boot from that CD and run the memory test for a couple of hours or overnight to stress test the memory. If you get errors with this test you have a bad memory module, if you have more than one memory module installed remove all but one and re-run the test, test each module individually until you find the bad one.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315223) on this.  Basically the solutions that they suggest are:

- Take out the memory modules one by one to see if any of them are faulty.
- See if there are any drivers you can update
- Check the BIOS
- Check the adapters